# Debug EF Code First database generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, ef-code-first

I am wondering if there is some way to debug the Database generation of a ASP.NET MVC 3 application. I am encountering some problem: the database is not created and I have no error message.

**UPDATED**

Here's my connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SmartRent.Models.AdContext"  connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Here is my Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SmartRent.Models.AdContext>());
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Here is my EF DataContext:

```
namespace SmartRent.Models
{
    public class AdContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Ad> Ads { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CraneLocation> CraneLocations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception? I had random problem with migration with unexpected error. It solves by referencing -StartUpProjectName flag while migration

Comment: There is no exception. The web application simply start but the database is not created.

Comment: You should run Update-database command in Package manager console to create it. It has no connects with compilation

Comment: Are you sure Denis? Where I have to fire that command?

Comment: this looks funny to me: connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; -someone more expert can say, can you ever just connect to sqlexpress with no instance name?

Comment: @AngeloBad, have you got a database already created that you're referencing?  WHen I set up database first I used the quick steps here, which are focused on how to get another package set up, but it might be of use: http://weblogs.asp.net/paullitwin/archive/2011/08/11/use-mvc-scaffolding-in-database-first-mode.aspx

Comment: @LevinMagruder it sounds funny but EF can't work without connectionstring at all if Visual Studio works under .SQLExpress admin

Comment: Levin open VS -> View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console. Read this article to understand creating/migrating concepts: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: >>I am wondering if there is some way to debug the Database generation of a ASP.NET MVC 3 application.  MVC has nothing to do with the question. A MVC app using Oracale and ODBC? Access? This is a trivial EF problem. Start with simple working code and compare to your failing code. It's easy to install run the SQL profiler. Compare the working/failing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run my completed soln of my tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs
2. My code works, so modify my code/your code until it breaks/works.

The best way to solve this type of problem is to use the SQL profiler. Try to repro first with my code.

Answer (score 1):

From the Code First perspective alone...
this might help you [Entity Framework 4.3 doesn't create database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364750/entity-framework-4-3-doesnt-create-database/9745125#9745125)
and you have to work with PM console, there is no other way to get around problems (and **that's the best way to actually 'debug' what's going on**).
Each step in PM console has to result in success - and no exceptions, also read the comments as they often tell you  what might be wrong.
You could also run the `Update-Database -Script` to get a sense what is being created (before it's actually created).
And SQLExpress is default (I think), so you can drop the connection string to test things w/o specifying the connection.
In short, some consistency with around this and playing/understanding the PM console, helped me get control of things, might help you too.
Also manually removing previous Db-s created (by Code First if you have any at all), removing migrations if existing, recompiling and then re-running, so the usual debugging techniques:).

Answer (score 0):

See: [Debugging Package Manager Console Update-Database Seed Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718510/debugging-package-manager-console-update-database-seed-method)

Clipped from the answer

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```