# How can i use breakpoint while running seed method from Package Manager console

Tags: breakpoints

Is there any option to put breakpoin then start debugging while running **Update-Database -Verbose** from Package Manager console?

Comment: @SB2055: nope! please update if you find any way :-)

Answer (score 0):

if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

from [Debug code-first Entity Framework migration codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169020/debug-code-first-entity-framework-migration-codes)