# Can one set a breakpoint in EF code first migrations seed method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am having trouble with something in the `Seed` method in the `Configure.cs` for my entity framework 6 code-first migration process. I am running the `Update-Database -verbose` command in the `Package Manager Console`, and tried to set breakpoints (in VS studio web express 2013) in the c# code of the `Seed` method. But even if I put it on the first statement in the method, it is not hit, although the console displays `running seed method` (and subsequently breaks due to my error)

So can one somehow set breakpoints in the `Seed` method? If not, what is the best way to debug that code?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26567885/1336590 ? Basically, run `Seed` through the application and not in the PM console.

Comment: See this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2013/02/12/seeding-and-debugging-entity-framework-ef-dbs.aspx

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's not possible directly within source code but you can attach the debugger via source code. Please see [this link](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-debug-entity-framework-migration-seeding) for details:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

The other option would be to run the migration via source code as explained above:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```

Comment: It was working view hours ago ... this is a cached version; http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-debug-entity-framework-migration-seeding&strip=1

Comment: Here is another article I found looking for this same question: http://blog.theodybrothers.com/2015/09/debugging-your-seed-method-when-running.html

Answer (score 1):

`Update-Database` runs out of your debugging session so you cannot set a breakpoint. You'll want to run your Seed method elsewhere from within your code, like a dummy method, that you can kick off from within your app.