# EF Core Add Migration Debugging

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration, entity-framework-core

How can I step into `OnModelCreating` with a breakpoint and see if my logic is wrong or if the `ModelBuilder` is doing something I'm not expecting?  I've seen lots of posts on how to debug the actual migration, but nothing on how to watch how the model code is being generated.

I'm trying to implement some custom attributes on some of my entities, and it's being ignored; I'd like to see what my configuration is doing as it's generating the model code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one set a breakpoint in EF code first migrations seed method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858289/can-one-set-a-breakpoint-in-ef-code-first-migrations-seed-method)

Comment: They may have similar answers, but they are entirely different questions.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You should be able to call `Debugger.Launch()` in your code. The just-in-time debugger should prompt you to attach a debugger when it hits that line.

Comment: Thanks!  That's twice you've helped me. :)

Comment: It's my job. ;) I try to make sure people can use what I create. Every question asked becomes input into future enhancements.

Comment: @bricelam should this work in EF Core 2.0 as well? Debugger will not attach correctly there.

Comment: I'm trying to attach a Debugger, but it won't step into my code. Are there any prerequisits?

Comment: A win32 exception is being thrown for me(ef core2.0) -- kernelbase.pdb not loaded

Comment: @JohnOsborne, I'm having the same problem when calling Debugger.Launch(); in the OnConfiguring method of my DbContext while running Add-Migration

Comment: @lnx51 any luck?

Comment: Hey everyone - try `Debugger.Break()` instead.

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` if you don't want to amend the referenced namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate method would be to create your own console app or unit test and debug that. Use this snippet by bricelam [from the ef github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9339#issuecomment-320295069)

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var reporter = new OperationReporter(
        new OperationReportHandler(
            m => Console.WriteLine("  error: " + m),
            m => Console.WriteLine("   warn: " + m),
            m => Console.WriteLine("   info: " + m),
            m => Console.WriteLine("verbose: " + m)));

    var designTimeServices = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton(db.GetService<IHistoryRepository>())
        .AddSingleton(db.GetService<IMigrationsIdGenerator>())
        .AddSingleton(db.GetService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>())
        .AddSingleton(db.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>())
        .AddSingleton(db.Model)
        .AddSingleton(db.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>())
        .AddSingleton(db.GetService<IDatabaseProvider>())
        .AddSingleton<MigrationsCodeGeneratorDependencies>()
        .AddSingleton<ICSharpHelper, CSharpHelper>()
        .AddSingleton<CSharpMigrationOperationGeneratorDependencies>()
        .AddSingleton<ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator, CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator>()
        .AddSingleton<CSharpSnapshotGeneratorDependencies>()
        .AddSingleton<ICSharpSnapshotGenerator, CSharpSnapshotGenerator>()
        .AddSingleton<CSharpMigrationsGeneratorDependencies>()
        .AddSingleton<IMigrationsCodeGenerator, CSharpMigrationsGenerator>()
        .AddSingleton<IOperationReporter>(reporter)
        .AddSingleton<MigrationsScaffolderDependencies>()
        .AddSingleton<MigrationsScaffolder>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var scaffolder = designTimeServices.GetRequiredService<MigrationsScaffolder>();

    var migration = scaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(
        "MyMigration",
        "MyApp.Data");

    File.WriteAllText(
        migration.MigrationId + migration.FileExtension,
        migration.MigrationCode);
    File.WriteAllText(
        migration.MigrationId + ".Designer" + migration.FileExtension,
        migration.MetadataCode);
    File.WriteAllText(migration.SnapshotName + migration.FileExtension,
        migration.SnapshotCode);
}
```