# EF Core CLI Tools prerequisits for attaching the debugger

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

I was trying to debug the OnModelCreated from my DBContext as described here: [EF Core Add Migration Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663537/ef-core-add-migration-debugging) by inserting `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`

Then I ran the `> dotnet ef migrations list` command and got the prompt for attaching a Debugger. I choose the running VS, where the correct solution was loaded.

Then I saw disassembled files and warnings about not finding the debugger.cpp and whatsoever. I choose to set a breakpoint directly after the aforementioned `Debugger.Launch()` which then told me

> Breakpoint, will not be hit, since no symbols have been loaded"

Well - the module window, will most likely know something about that.
So openening the module window and looking for my .dll. - There it is - with a small red cross on top.

Right-Click to the module: Symbol load information states:

> This module is a pre-compiled binary created by the ngen.exe tool. The debugger does not attempt to load symbols for these binaries, but will instead load symbols for original dll/exe when it is loaded by the .NET Runtime.

And Symbol Status from the File states:
| Name | SymbolStatus | Process |
| DataAccess.Migrations.dll | Native debugger skipped loading symbols for managed module. | [21808] dotnet.exe |

As I write this, it seems, VS tries to debug the native code instead of the managed code. Is there a way to solve this or jump into "mixed mode debugging"?

Comment: Could you debug your app now? Any update, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the debugger is skipping files not in the .NET environment.
Solution: **Check** Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code

For mixed mode: 
Project name -> properties-> debugging -> Debugger Type:

[image]

Comment: `Just My Code` is already enabled.  
The form you are showing is c++. dotnet (cli) itself probably is non managed as well, but the dll, I want to debug is a dotnet ef core Migration dll. I cannot set the parameters for my project or solution, since it's not native code.

Comment: @TGlatzer If it's a C# project,  In the <Project> Property Pages dialog box, select the Debug tab, and then select Enable native code debugging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode#to-enable-mixed-mode-debugging-c-or-vb-calling-app

Comment: I'd really like to follow your advice, but .NET Core projects don't seem to have that button.