# Visual Studio 2015 crashing each time I run Update-Database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-migrations

Each time I run Update-Database from the package manager console, Visual Studio 2015 is crashing. It happens to be running my migrations Configuration.Seed method at the time. Any idea where I should look to find out what's going on?

Comment: If this could help : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29ef381f-f465-463c-b64b-aed07d07ac63/vs2012-package-manager-crashes-on-updatedatabase-using-entity-first-code-migrations-with-seed?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: capture a dump (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) of the crashing VS2015. Open the crash dump in windbg, fix the debug symbols (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046), run **!analyze -v** and post the output.

Comment: I found this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169020/debug-code-first-entity-framework-migration-codes) and it helped me debug my Seed method which was throwing an unhandled exception. I'll try your suggestion @magicandre1981 to see why that would bring down VS, however.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @MothCreek, I never did get back around to trying the solution proposed by magicandre1981. I did place a try catch around my seed method code and found where it was throwing an exception. Once I corrected that the seed method worked just fine. I would have expected to get a stack trace in the output window or package manager window though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a non-trivial chance that the crash is caused by project's code and not the inner working of Visual Studio.

As [suggested by m_david in a question linked by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17756198/5282087), the first step is to add following code at the beginning of `Seed()`¹:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
}
```

This will cause a prompt² to appear that will ask whether to launch the debugger in a new instance of Visual Studio or another currently running one.

After that, the debugger's output will be logged to *Debug* output of that VS instance, and unhandled exceptions will be treated as break points - with highlighting the offending line of code, exception details and all that.

In my case, the crash was caused by a recursive `set()` operation in a member of one of the entities, which resulted in a `StackOverflowException`.

---

¹ Or your `DbMigrationsConfiguration` subclass's constructor, if the crash happens earlier. Or possibly some other place.

² So remember to comment that code out when you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful! The issue was a validation issue in a new column that I had added to one of the tables. It didn't show up until I added this code.