# For EF: Is it possible to debug a migration in VSCode?

Tags: entity-framework, vscode-debugger

With Entity Framework, is it possible to debug a migration with VSCode?

I added this to my launch configurations:

```
    {
      "name": "Migrate",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "dotnet: build",
      "program": "dotnet",
      "args": ["ef", "database", "update"]
    }
```

And indeed, this will run the migration. It will not stop at a breakpoint I set in the migration though.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Not sure this would work from VS Code, but here are some ways in this might be doable: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17169020/1220550 ... or else, consider doing it using the free Community Edition of Visual Studio, which has much better debugging options for .NET/C# than what VS Code has to offer.

Comment: Thanks @PeterB I'm on a Mac and tried the community edition of Visual Studio, but was not really impressed tbh