# MVC EntityFramework Code-First Migration is executing, but Seed not taking effect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I've been following the below tutorial in an attempt to set up Code-First EntityFramework Migrations in my MVC5 App and then Seed my database with some sample data for use:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

My project is now successfully building, and I can go through all of the steps to modify my initial database:

```
 - update-database -targetmigration:"0" -force -verbose
 - *Delete Current Migrations
 - add-migration InitialCreate
 - update-database
```

When the last command completes, my `Seed` method is supposedly being ran (and I can see the tables being created using the `-verbose` parameter). However, there is no entry in my `INV_Assets` table where there should be one as specified by my current seeding.

Can anyone offer some input as to why my `Seed` method does not appear to be taking effect, though it seems to be running?

---

**InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryInitializer.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using InventoryTracker.Models;
using InventoryTracker.DAL;
using WebMatrix.WebData;

namespace InventoryTracker.DAL
{
    public class InventoryInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<InventoryTrackerContext>
    {
        InventoryTrackerContext context = new InventoryTrackerContext();

        protected override void Seed(InventoryTrackerContext context)
        {
            List<INV_Locations> invLocs = getLocations();
            invLocs.ForEach(s => context.INV_Locations.Add(s));
            List<INV_Manufacturers> invManufacturers = getManufacturers();
            invManufacturers.ForEach(s => context.INV_Manufacturers.Add(s));
            List<INV_Models> invModels = getModels();
            invModels.ForEach(s => context.INV_Models.Add(s));
            List<INV_Statuses> invStatuses = getStatuses();
            invStatuses.ForEach(s => context.INV_Statuses.Add(s));
            List<INV_Types> invTypes = getTypes();
            invTypes.ForEach(s => context.INV_Types.Add(s));
            List<INV_Vendors> invVendors = getVendors();
            invVendors.ForEach(s => context.INV_Vendors.Add(s));

            List<INV_Assets> invAssets = getAssets();
            invAssets.ForEach(s => context.INV_Assets.Add(s));

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        #region Seed Assets
        private List<INV_Assets> getAssets()
        {
            List<INV_Assets> testAssets = new List<INV_Assets>
            {
                new INV_Assets
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    ip_address = "10.10.135.38",
                    mac_address = "10.10.177.44",
                    note = "",
                    owner = "John Smith",
                    cost = 35,
                    po_number = "G348",
                    invoice_number = 1447,
                    serial_number = "JX14582Y",
                    asset_tag_number = "293548195023",
                    acquired_date = Convert.ToDateTime(10212014),
                    disposed_date = null,
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now,
                    location_id = 1,
                    manufacturer_id = 1,
                    model_id = 1,
                    status_id = 2,
                    type_id = 3,
                    vendor_id = 3
                }
            };
            return testAssets;
        }
        #endregion

        [Seed Locations]
        [Seed Manufacturers]

        #region Seed Models
        private List<INV_Models> getModels()
        {
            List<INV_Models> testModels = new List<INV_Models>
            {
                new INV_Models
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    model_description = "XTERAV12",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Models
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    model_description = "5330",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Models
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    model_description = "Sunblade 6000",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                }
            };
            return testModels;
        }
        #endregion

        [Seed Statuses]
        [Seed Types]
        [Seed Vendors]
     }
   }
```

---

**InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using InventoryTracker.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace InventoryTracker.DAL
{
    public class InventoryTrackerContext : DbContext
    {
        public InventoryTrackerContext()
            : base("InventoryTrackerContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<INV_Assets> INV_Assets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Models> INV_Models { get;set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Manufacturers> INV_Manufacturers { get;set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Types> INV_Types { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Locations> INV_Locations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Vendors> INV_Vendors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Statuses> INV_Statuses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="InventoryTrackerContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\InventoryTrackerDBDev.mdf;Initial Catalog=InventoryTrackerDBDev;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <!--<add name="PRISMContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=PrismDBdev5;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\PrismDBdev5.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- Active Directory Authentication - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="GridMvc" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages></system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
      <contexts>
          <context type="InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext, InventoryTracker">
              <databaseInitializer type="InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryInitializer, InventoryTracker" />
          </context>
      </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

---

---

**EDIT**:

Ok, so it seems where I was going wrong was setting up my Seed in the wrong location. It should have all along been in the `InventoryTracer.Migrations.Configuration.cs` file... which had no seeding coded into it... which is why I was not getting any inserted data after Seed... :/

I've now moved seeding into the proper seed method in the `Configuration.cs` file, but I'm getting an error: `Invalid cast from 'Int32' to 'DateTime'.`

The full trace from `Package Manager Console` is as follows:

```
Running Seed method.
System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'Int32' to 'DateTime'.
   at System.Int32.System.IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(Int32 value)
   at InventoryTracker.Migrations.Configuration.getAssets() in c:\James-Projects\InventoryTracker\InventoryTracker\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 57
   at InventoryTracker.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(InventoryTrackerContext context) in c:\James-Projects\InventoryTracker\InventoryTracker\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 47
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Invalid cast from 'Int32' to 'DateTime'.
```

I'm not quite sure where the cast error is occurring though, as Lines 47/57 of my `Configuration.cs` respectively are:

```
47 - List<INV_Assets> invAssets = getAssets();
57 - List<INV_Assets> testAssets = new List<INV_Assets>
```

My guess would be it is revolving around line 71 - `acquired_date = Convert.ToDateTime(10212014),`.

Anyone have thoughts on how to resolve this?

---

**Configuration.cs**:

```
namespace InventoryTracker.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using InventoryTracker.Models;
    using InventoryTracker.DAL;
    using WebMatrix.WebData;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
            List<INV_Locations> invLocs = getLocations();
            invLocs.ForEach(s => context.INV_Locations.Add(s));
            List<INV_Manufacturers> invManufacturers = getManufacturers();
            invManufacturers.ForEach(s => context.INV_Manufacturers.Add(s));
            List<INV_Models> invModels = getModels();
            invModels.ForEach(s => context.INV_Models.Add(s));
            List<INV_Statuses> invStatuses = getStatuses();
            invStatuses.ForEach(s => context.INV_Statuses.Add(s));
            List<INV_Types> invTypes = getTypes();
            invTypes.ForEach(s => context.INV_Types.Add(s));
            List<INV_Vendors> invVendors = getVendors();
            invVendors.ForEach(s => context.INV_Vendors.Add(s));

            List<INV_Assets> invAssets = getAssets();
            invAssets.ForEach(s => context.INV_Assets.Add(s));

            context.SaveChanges();
        }


        #region Seed Assets
        private List<INV_Assets> getAssets()
        {
            List<INV_Assets> testAssets = new List<INV_Assets>
            {
                new INV_Assets
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    ip_address = "10.10.135.38",
                    mac_address = "10.10.177.44",
                    note = "",
                    owner = "John Smith",
                    cost = 35,
                    po_number = "G348",
                    invoice_number = 1447,
                    serial_number = "JX14582Y",
                    asset_tag_number = "293548195023",
                    acquired_date = Convert.ToDateTime(10212014),
                    disposed_date = null,
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now,
                    Location_Id = 1,
                    Manufacturer_Id = 1,
                    Model_Id = 1,
                    Status_Id = 2,
                    Type_Id = 3,
                    Vendor_Id = 3
                }
            };
            return testAssets;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Seed Locations
        private List<INV_Locations> getLocations()
        {
            List<INV_Locations> testLocations = new List<INV_Locations>
            {
                new INV_Locations
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    location_dept = "IT",
                    location_room = "Server",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Locations
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    location_dept = "Break Room",
                    location_room = "Kitchen",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Locations
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    location_dept = "Accounting",
                    location_room = "Conference",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                }
            };
            return testLocations;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Seed Manufacturers
        private List<INV_Manufacturers> getManufacturers()
        {
            List<INV_Manufacturers> testManufacturers = new List<INV_Manufacturers>
            {
                new INV_Manufacturers
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    manufacturer_description = "Samsung",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Manufacturers
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    manufacturer_description = "MITEL",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Manufacturers
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    manufacturer_description = "Oracle",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                }
            };
            return testManufacturers;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Seed Models
        private List<INV_Models> getModels()
        {
            List<INV_Models> testModels = new List<INV_Models>
            {
                new INV_Models
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    model_description = "XTERAV12",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Models
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    model_description = "5330",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Models
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    model_description = "Sunblade 6000",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                }
            };
            return testModels;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Seed Statuses
        private List<INV_Statuses> getStatuses()
        {
            List<INV_Statuses> testStatuses = new List<INV_Statuses>
            {
                new INV_Statuses
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    status_description = "AVAILABLE",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Statuses
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    status_description = "SIGNEDOUT",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Statuses
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    status_description = "RECYCLED",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Statuses
                {
                    Id = 4,
                    status_description = "AUCTIONED",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                }
            };
            return testStatuses;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Seed Types
        private List<INV_Types> getTypes()
        {
            List<INV_Types> testTypes = new List<INV_Types>
            {
                new INV_Types
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    type_description = "Server",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Types
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    type_description = "IP Phone",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Types
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    type_description = "Monitor",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                }
            };
            return testTypes;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Seed Vendors
        private List<INV_Vendors> getVendors()
        {
            List<INV_Vendors> testVendors = new List<INV_Vendors>
            {
                new INV_Vendors
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    vendor_name = "Oracle",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Vendors
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    vendor_name = "Centriq",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                },
                new INV_Vendors
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    vendor_name = "Samsung",
                    created_by = "Admin",
                    created_date = DateTime.Now
                }
            };
            return testVendors;
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

---

**EDIT2**:

I *think* I've got the `Invalid cast from 'Int32' to 'DateTime'.` taken care of by changing `acquired_date = Convert.ToDateTime(10212014)` to `acquired_date = DateTime.ParseExact("10212014", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, but now I have a new error.

When I run the `update-database` command, my Seed method now fails with error `Ambiguous match found`. By placing the following code at the topmost part of my `Seed()` I tried to get some more information:

```
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        }
```

When the code reaches `invAssets.ForEach(s => context.INV_Assets.Add(s));` the Debugger that I launched catches with `An exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Ambiguous match found.`

Anyone have thoughts on what is causing this? I could see potential of an `Ambiguous` error were I adding more than one test record, but at this time I only have the one record being seeded for `INV_Assets`.

Following [Soren Gustenhoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4243747/soren-gustenhoff) suggestions, I changed the `Foreach => Add()` to use `.AddRange()` and added a preliminary `context.SaveChanges()` before the `getAssets()` is called, but that only resulted in the following when the `AddRange(invTypes)` is called?

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

**CODE**:
            context.INV_Types.AddRange(invTypes); // exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
            //context.SaveChanges();
            List invVendors = getVendors();
            context.INV_Vendors.AddRange(invVendors);
            context.SaveChanges(); // Commenting this flags [getVendors()] with the Ambiguous Error?

```
        List<INV_Assets> invAssets = getAssets();
        context.INV_Assets.AddRange(invAssets);

        context.SaveChanges();
```

Going back to only having the one `context.SaveChanges()` at the end, my `getVendors()` is flagging with the `AmbiguousMatchException` first now???

Comment: What is `10212014` supposed to represent?  If it is a date of format `MMddyyyy`, then perhaps a change to `Convert.ToDateTime("2014-10-21")` would be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brendan. If you check my Edit, I think I got the data issue fixed, but am having a new issue.

Answer (score 3):

You setup relations in your INV_Assets that haven't been created yet.

EF Context won't create primary keys untill you have run saveChanges

i would recommend you to do this

```
List<INV_Types> invTypes = getTypes();
invTypes.ForEach(s => context.INV_Types.Add(s));
context.INV_Types.AddRange(invTypes);
List<INV_Vendors> invVendors = getVendors();
context.INV_Vendors.AddRange(invVendors);

context.SaveChanges();

List<INV_Assets> invAssets = getAssets();
context.INV_Assets.AddRange(invAssets);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Btw. Notice the addRange instead of foreach -> add.

Ps.
For debugging seed method, see this: [Debugging Package Manager Console Update-Database Seed Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718510/debugging-package-manager-console-update-database-seed-method)

I hope that helped :)

Comment: Soren, thanks for the reply. I've done your suggestions (really appreciate the debug link!) but I'm having new issues. I did an EDIT above to reflect the changes, but since I maxed out the character limit for a post I created a new question for the specific new issue if you want to take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802953/mvc-entityframework-code-first-migrations-seed-failing-with-dbupdateexceptio

Comment: Soren, quick comment. I'm still having some issues with my `Seed()` (everything working except for the seeding of `INV_Assets`, but I noticed something strange. When I use the `.AddRange()` as you have suggested, each seeding of the other tables occurs 4 times (instead of 3 distinct records, I end up with 4 copies of the same 3 for 12)? When I switched my code back to using the `Foreach( => .Add())` method though, the other table records are populating just as I would expect. Thoughts on why this may be happening? New issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804300/