# MVC EntityFramework Code-First Migrations - Seed() Failing with DbUpdateException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on a somewhat simple InventoryTracker MVC5 Application wherein I'm having some issues with getting my LocalDatabase to `Seed()`.

When I run the `update-database` command on my below code, I get an exception as follows on the line `context.INV_Types.AddRange(invTypes)`:

`An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.`

*Inner Exception*: `The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.`

---

**CODE**:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext context)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        }

        List<INV_Locations> invLocs = getLocations();
        context.INV_Locations.AddRange(invLocs);
        List<INV_Manufacturers> invManufacturers = getManufacturers();
        context.INV_Manufacturers.AddRange(invManufacturers);
        List<INV_Models> invModels = getModels();
        context.INV_Models.AddRange(invModels);
        List<INV_Statuses> invStatuses = getStatuses();
        context.INV_Statuses.AddRange(invStatuses);
        List<INV_Types> invTypes = getTypes();
        context.INV_Types.AddRange(invTypes); // EXCEPTION?
        List<INV_Vendors> invVendors = getVendors();
        context.INV_Vendors.AddRange(invVendors);

        context.SaveChanges(); // Was told I needed to Save the other seeds before the Assets to ensure primary keys are created in the other tables?

        List<INV_Assets> invAssets = getAssets();
        context.INV_Assets.AddRange(invAssets);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private List<INV_Types> getTypes()
    {
        List<INV_Types> testTypes = new List<INV_Types>
        {
            new INV_Types
            {
                Id = 1,
                type_description = "Server",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Types
            {
                Id = 2,
                type_description = "IP Phone",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Types
            {
                Id = 3,
                type_description = "Monitor",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            }
        };
        return testTypes;
    }

    private List<INV_Assets> getAssets()
        {
            List<INV_Assets> testAssets = new List<INV_Assets>
            {
              new INV_Assets
              {
                Id = 1,
                ip_address = "10.10.135.38",
                mac_address = "10.10.177.44",
                note = "",
                owner = "John Smith",
                cost = 35,
                po_number = "G348",
                invoice_number = 1447,
                serial_number = "JX14582Y",
                asset_tag_number = "293548195023",
                //acquired_date = Convert.ToDateTime(10212014),
                acquired_date = DateTime.ParseExact("10212014", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                disposed_date = null,
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now,
                Location_Id = 1,
                Manufacturer_Id = 1,
                Model_Id = 1,
                Status_Id = 2,
                Type_Id = 3,
                Vendor_Id = 3
            }
        };
        return testAssets;
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas for what may be causing this in the structure of my `Seed()` for `INV_Types`?

I thought it might be something where I needed to save my changes to the context prior to the `getTYpes()`, but adding `context.SaveChanges()` after the `.AddRange(invStatuses)` only results in the same error with that new `context.SaveChanges()`??

I've included my other seed methods below to help if anyone sees something I am overlooking:

```
    #region Seed Locations
    private List<INV_Locations> getLocations()
    {
        List<INV_Locations> testLocations = new List<INV_Locations>
        {
            new INV_Locations
            {
                Id = 1,
                location_dept = "IT",
                location_room = "Server",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Locations
            {
                Id = 2,
                location_dept = "Break Room",
                location_room = "Kitchen",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Locations
            {
                Id = 3,
                location_dept = "Accounting",
                location_room = "Conference",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            }
        };
        return testLocations;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Seed Manufacturers
    private List<INV_Manufacturers> getManufacturers()
    {
        List<INV_Manufacturers> testManufacturers = new List<INV_Manufacturers>
        {
            new INV_Manufacturers
            {
                Id = 1,
                manufacturer_description = "Samsung",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Manufacturers
            {
                Id = 2,
                manufacturer_description = "MITEL",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Manufacturers
            {
                Id = 3,
                manufacturer_description = "Oracle",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            }
        };
        return testManufacturers;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Seed Models
    private List<INV_Models> getModels()
    {
        List<INV_Models> testModels = new List<INV_Models>
        {
            new INV_Models
            {
                Id = 1,
                model_description = "XTERAV12",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Models
            {
                Id = 2,
                model_description = "5330",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Models
            {
                Id = 3,
                model_description = "Sunblade 6000",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            }
        };
        return testModels;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Seed Statuses
    private List<INV_Statuses> getStatuses()
    {
        List<INV_Statuses> testStatuses = new List<INV_Statuses>
        {
            new INV_Statuses
            {
                Id = 1,
                status_description = "AVAILABLE",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Statuses
            {
                Id = 2,
                status_description = "SIGNEDOUT",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Statuses
            {
                Id = 3,
                status_description = "RECYCLED",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Statuses
            {
                Id = 4,
                status_description = "AUCTIONED",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            }
        };
        return testStatuses;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Seed Types
    private List<INV_Types> getTypes()
    {
        List<INV_Types> testTypes = new List<INV_Types>
        {
            new INV_Types
            {
                Id = 1,
                type_description = "Server",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Types
            {
                Id = 2,
                type_description = "IP Phone",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Types
            {
                Id = 3,
                type_description = "Monitor",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            }
        };
        return testTypes;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Seed Vendors
    private List<INV_Vendors> getVendors()
    {
        List<INV_Vendors> testVendors = new List<INV_Vendors>
        {
            new INV_Vendors
            {
                Id = 1,
                vendor_name = "Oracle",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Vendors
            {
                Id = 2,
                vendor_name = "Centriq",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            },
            new INV_Vendors
            {
                Id = 3,
                vendor_name = "Samsung",
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now
            }
        };
        return testVendors;
    }
    #endregion
```

---

**EDIT:**

As [IronMan84](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391762/ironman84) pointed out, I had mistakenly copy-pasted to where I had several instances of each entity with the same `Id` value (ex. 1, 2, 1 instead of 1, 2, 3). However, the error is still persisting except now at the following line:

```
        context.INV_Vendors.AddRange(invVendors);

        context.SaveChanges(); // DbUpdateException!

        List<INV_Assets> invAssets = getAssets();
```

**EDIT2**: Added the *Inner Exception* detail to the error originally listed. `The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated`.

**EDIT3**: To better diagnose the problem, I tried adding `context.SaveChanges()` after each  of the `.AddRange()` calls, but the very first instance after `context.INV_Locations.AddRange(invLocs)` results in the same error:

`An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.`

*Inner Exception*: `The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.`

I can only imagine this is referencing my `getLocations()` setting the `[created_date]` value to `DateTime.Now`, but I'm not sure what the issue is?

In my Model I have defined the property as:

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
```

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 of the Types in your `getTypes()` method have an `Id` value of 1. EF doesn't like that conflict and thus bombs out.

EDIT: The error that you've mentioned in the comments (`The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.`) is only caused by an object having a `DateTime` property whose current value is set to a date before January 1, 1753 (most likely it's set to `DateTime.MinValue`, which is 1/1/0001).

What causes that is that EF maps C#'s `DateTime` type to SQL's `datetime` type (as opposed to `datetime2`, which can go back to 1/1/0001), which has that minimum date requirement mentioned above. When you try to save an object that has a date *before* 1/1/1753 SQL thinks that you're trying to save a `datetime2` in a column that's of type `datetime` and blows up.

The solution is to debug it and figure out which record(s) have properties that are still set to a bad date (like `DateTime.MinValue`) and adjust the code to edit those properties accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply IronMan. I got caught in the old copy-paste error... I had hoped that would solve my issue, but now I receive the same error at the `context.SaveChanges()` right after `AddRange(invVendors)` and before the `getAssets()` call (see Edit above for clarity).

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: Here it is: `The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.`

Comment: Thanks IronMan, and I think I see what you mean. I'm just confused about how there can be a bad date in this case (see Edit3 above). This occurs even just after seeding for my `INV_Locations` table, and the only `DateTime` being specified is setting the `[created_date]` property to `= DateTime.Now`?

Comment: Are there any other `DateTime` properties on your `Location` class? Because those automatically are set to `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Hmm... there is one more. Besides the `[created_date]` property I detailed in Edit3, there is also a `[modified-date]` property which I am currently not setting (no need for a new record). If you are correct and this is causing the issue, how would I go about getting around it since I am not specifying the `[modified_date]` in my `Seed()`?

Comment: You would need to set it in order for the record to save. Even if you don't set it, EF tries to save it (unless it's nullable)

Comment: What would you suggest specifying it as, since I cannot do `[modified_date] = null`?

Comment: You have to set it to some value, then. I would recommend the same value as for `CreatedDate`.

Comment: Thanks IronMan! That worked, but now I'm getting a new kind of exception (made a new quesiton for the new Exception): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804300/mvc-entityframework-code-first-migrations-seed-failing-with-ambiguousmatchex