# MVC EntityFramework Code-First Migrations - Seed() Failing with AmbiguousMatchException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on a somewhat simple InventoryTracker MVC5 Application wherein I'm having some issues with getting my LocalDatabase to `Seed()`.

When I run the `update-database` command on my below code, I get an exception as follows on the line `context.INV_Assets.AddRange(invAssets)`:

`An exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Ambiguous match found.`

Anyone have thoughts on what in my `INV_Assets - Seed()` is causing the issue? There is no InnerException and I cannot seem to get more detail on it.

[image: AmibguousMatchException]

---

**CODE**:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext context)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        }

        List<INV_Locations> invLocs = getLocations();
        context.INV_Locations.AddRange(invLocs);
        context.SaveChanges(); 
        List<INV_Manufacturers> invManufacturers = getManufacturers();
        context.INV_Manufacturers.AddRange(invManufacturers);
        context.SaveChanges();
        List<INV_Models> invModels = getModels();
        context.INV_Models.AddRange(invModels);
        context.SaveChanges();
        List<INV_Statuses> invStatuses = getStatuses();
        context.INV_Statuses.AddRange(invStatuses);
        context.SaveChanges();
        List<INV_Types> invTypes = getTypes();
        context.INV_Types.AddRange(invTypes);
        context.SaveChanges();
        List<INV_Vendors> invVendors = getVendors();
        context.INV_Vendors.AddRange(invVendors);
        context.SaveChanges(); // Everything OK to this point.

        List<INV_Assets> invAssets = getAssets();
        context.INV_Assets.AddRange(invAssets); // System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException!

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private List<INV_Assets> getAssets()
        {
            List<INV_Assets> testAssets = new List<INV_Assets>
            {
              new INV_Assets
              {
                Id = 1,
                ip_address = "10.10.135.38",
                mac_address = "10.10.177.44",
                note = "",
                owner = "John Smith",
                cost = 35,
                po_number = "G348",
                invoice_number = 1447,
                serial_number = "JX14582Y",
                asset_tag_number = "293548195023",
                //acquired_date = Convert.ToDateTime(10212014),
                acquired_date = DateTime.ParseExact("10212014", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                disposed_date = null,
                created_by = "Admin",
                created_date = DateTime.Now,
                modified_by = "Admin",
                modified_date = DateTime.Now,
                Location_Id = 1,
                Manufacturer_Id = 1,
                Model_Id = 1,
                Status_Id = 2,
                Type_Id = 3,
                Vendor_Id = 3
            }
        };
        return testAssets;
    }
```

---

**EDIT**:

**INV_Assets.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using GridMvc.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using InventoryTracker.Models;

namespace InventoryTracker.Models
{
    [GridTable(PagingEnabled = true, PageSize = 30)]
    public class INV_Assets
    {
        // Setting GridColumn Annotations allows you to use AutoGenerateColumns on view to auto create the Grid based on the model.


        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Model_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Models model_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Manufacturer_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Manufacturers manufacturer_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Type_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Type_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Types type_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Location_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Locations location_id { get; set; }

        public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Vendor_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Vendors vendor_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Statuses status_id { get; set; }

        public string ip_address { get; set; }

        public string mac_address { get; set; }

        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }


        public int invoice_number{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string serial_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string created_by { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime modified_date { get; set; }

        public string modified_by { get; set; }

        // Flag to specify if item is available? (Not signed out, not auctioned, recycled, etc.)
        //public bool available { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT2**:

Full Result in `Package Manager Console` from entering command `update-database` to the result of `Ambiguous Match found`:

```
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
   at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
   at System.Type.GetProperty(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression expression, String propertyOrFieldName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.CreateBaseGetter(Type declaringType, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.PocoPropertyAccessorStrategy.GetNavigationPropertyValue(RelatedEnd relatedEnd)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapper`1.GetNavigationPropertyValue(RelatedEnd relatedEnd)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupFKValuesFromNonAddedReferences()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddSingleObject(EntitySet entitySet, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, String argumentName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<AddRange>b__f(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action`1 action, EntityState newState, IEnumerable entities, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.AddRange(IEnumerable entities)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 entities)
   at InventoryTracker.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(InventoryTrackerContext context) in c:\James-Projects\InventoryTracker\InventoryTracker\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 91
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Ambiguous match found.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is in the very similar property names. For example in `INV_Assets` you have

```
public int Model_Id { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
public virtual INV_Models model_id { get; set; }
```

Both of them are named almost identically. The difference is just in first symbol case. Based on the stack trace and Entity framework source it doing such thing in `EntityProxyFactory` class:

```
public virtual Func<object, object> CreateBaseGetter(Type declaringType, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
  Func<object, object> nonProxyGetter = 
        ((Expression<Func<object, object>>) (instance 
            => 
                Expression.PropertyOrField(
                    (Expression) Expression.Convert(instance, declaringType),
                    propertyInfo.Name))
        ).Compile();
```

It passes property name as string. And Reflection can't understand what property it should use, because there are two properties with the same name and different case.

Here is a sample program with the same logic that also fails with the same `Ambiguous match found.` exception - https://dotnetfiddle.net/BUIAwK

As usual referenced object named with `ID` in the property name, so you just need to update your code to

```
public int Model_Id { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much Sergey! That was it :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello again Analytic Lunatic :)

Well if you look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ambiguousmatchexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Then you will see that quote: "The exception that is thrown when binding to a member results in more than one member matching the binding criteria. This class cannot be inherited."

Do you have more properties in INV_Assets that we cant see ?
Can you please show us the class?

Comment: Hello! Sure thing, I have added the `INV_Assets.cs` above in my EDIT.